# telegra bot на aiogram как использовать состояния в callback_query_handler?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Использую aiogram для управления ботом
машина состояний:

```
from aiogram.utils.helper import Helper, HelperMode, ListItem

class StateMach(Helper):
    mode =HelperMode.snake_case
    STATE_VIP= ListItem()
    STATE_START= ListItem()
```

Код обработчиков:

```
@dp.message_handler(state= '*', commands=['vip'])
async def proc_vip_com(msg: types.Message):
    keyboard=InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    viplist = getvip()
    state = dp.current_state(user=msg.from_user.id)
    await state.set_state(StateMach.all()[0])
    for i in viplist:
        keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=i[2],callback_data=i[0]))
    await bot.send_message(msg.from_user.id, text="VIP раздел", reply_markup=keyboard)

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data, state = StateMach.STATE_VIP)
async def poc_callback_but(call:types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(call.id)
    await bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, text=call.data)
```

Почему не работает `callback_query_handler`, то есть не запускатся функция `proc_callback_but` и как это исправить?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

во-первых:

```
fsm aiogram use StatesGroup
```

пример:

```
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import StatesGroup, State

class States(StatesGroup):

    start: State = State()
    end: State = State()
    contact: State = State()
    geo: State = State()
    get_mail: State = State()
    mail_ver: State = State()
    save_json: State = State() 
    search_json: State = State()
    send_paste: State = State()
```

во-вторых callback можно сделать через:

```
posts_cb: CallbackData = CallbackData('post', 'id', 'action')` <br>
```

вот еще:

```
InlineKeyboardButton(text=text,
  callback_data=self.posts_cb.new(id=hash(call_back[val]),
  action=call_back[val]), )
```

и потом:

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(posts_cb.filter(action=["jsonbox"]))
```

и еще у aiogram есть [документация](https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/tree/master/examples)

вот [пример бота](https://github.com/dark0ghost/async_py_bot)

[чат aiogram](https://t.me/aiogram_ru)